# "Invitation to Discrete Math" Two player game, Open problem (?).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request

In the book "Invitation to discrete math" by J. Matousek and J. Nesetril,the
following exercise is proposed:

> Let $n \geq 2$ be a natural number. We consider the following game. Two players
> write a sequence of $0$s and $1$s/ They start with an empty line and alternate their moves. In each move, a player writes $0$ or $1$ to the end of the current sequence. A player losses if his digit completes a block of $n$ consecutive digits that repeats itself in the sequence for the second time (the two occurrences of the block may overlap).
> (a) prove that the game always finishes after finitely many steps.
> (b)  Suppose $n$ is odd. Prove the second player (the one who makes the second move) has a winning strategy.
> (c) Show that for $n=4$ the first player has a winning strategy.
> Unsolved question: Can you determine who has a winning strategy for some even n > 4?

I have solved all of the exercises above; in particular I found that for $n=6$
is again the second player who has a winning strategy.

My questions is: is it really an open problem? Have any of you solved it for other even $n$? Does it have a known name?

I would really appreciate anything that would allow me to search about it, since I have found
null at the moment. And, in case no one here knows much, I'll have to assume that it is just not of much interest, which is likely anyway.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the sort of thing you might expect to find in *Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays* by Berlekamp, Conway and Guy